# start and stop a thread repeatedly in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Here i have a method called Method1(), which will start a thread when the method is called odd time and stop same called even time. The below snippet works when i called the method through Button.onClick event. Is this the correct approach to pause and resume the thread ? Is my approach thread safe ?

```
Thread sampleThread = null;
..
..
..
private void Method1(){

    if(sampleThread == null){

        sampleThread =   new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

                while(true) {

                    Log.d(TAG,"Inside Thread");

                }
            }
        };
        sampleThread.start();

    }else {

        sampleThread.interrupt();

    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Method1` will be called frequently,I suggest you'd better set a flag,enable it to resume thread,and disable it to pause thread.because if you create and destroy a thread frequently,many CPU and memory will be wasted.You can use like this:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{
        volatile boolean isRunning = true;//make sure use volatile keyword
        @Override
        public void run() {

            while(isRunning) {

                Log.d(TAG,"Inside Thread");

            }
        }
        public void setRunning(boolean running){
            this.isRunning = running;
        }
    };
```

and when you want to pause,call `thread.setRunning(false)`,to restart it,call `thread.setRunning(true)`

If not so frequently,your solution almostly is ok,but I think you should add

```
sampleThread = null
```

after `sampleThread.interrupt();`,otherwise when you next pause it,it will interrupt a non-active thread,maybe there will throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a boolean variable and set it for the while loop. like this.

```
Boolean isActive = true;
```

then,

```
while(isActive ) {
   Log.d(TAG,"Inside Thread");
}
```

So, when you change the isActive to false then the thread will stop.